# Suppose the universe of all variables is the real numbers. Write the statement below in plain English

Tags: logic

Suppose the universe of all variables is the real numbers. Write the statement below in plain English, beginning with the words "Every non-zero real number has a ...".

$\forall_x \exists_y \left[ (x \neq 0) \rightarrow [(xy = 1) \wedge [\forall_w(w ≠ y) \rightarrow (xw ≠ 1)\right]]$

thanks not sure how to start this one

Comment: You seem to be missing two ]s

Comment: To say that $xy=1$ means that $y$ is the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) (or *reciprocal*) of $x$.

Comment: "Every nonzero real number has a unique right multiplicative inverse. " Honestly this is a bad question.  There really is no way to "solve" it unless you just know the answer in advance.  It is very possible someone has never seen that kind of language, and it certainly isn't plain English.  Going in the other direction might be a fair question.

Answer (score 0):

For every real number $x\ $ there exist exactly one real number $y$ such that $xy=1.$

Comment: That's every non-zero real number.

Answer (score 0):

Every non-zero real number has a unique right multiplicative inverse (or reciprocal).

Usually, it would be written:

$\forall x\in R:[x\neq 0 \implies \exists !y \in R: [(xy = 1) ]]$

Or..

$\forall x\in R:[x\neq 0 \implies \exists y \in R: [(xy = 1) \land \forall w \in R: [xw = 1 \implies w=y]]]$

(Multiplication assumed to be commutative, so we have reciprocal = left inverse = right inverse.)